# OMNeT++ and INET wireless communication with UDP

Tags: c++, networking, simulation, omnet++, inet

I have the following scenario: 3 wireless hosts H1, P1 and P2 (class WirelessHost) where H1 host has a custom UDP application while P1 and P2 use UDPEchoApp.

The idea is that H1 sends messages to the other two but in a scheduled way, e.g. H1 sends a message to P1 and wait for P1 to echo back, only upon reception of the echo from P1, it can send the message to P2.

My question is: how can I obtain this behavior? I am able to send a message to P1 and P2 but I don't know how to tell H1 to wait for the P1 reply before transmitting to P2.

Also another question about ARP. I am now using arpType = GlobalARP but I was wondering, how can I avoid that H1 sends ARP requests? How can I already tell H1 where to find certain hosts?

Since the network layer is not really necessary, is it possible to ignore it and use it just to forward the messages from the application layer to the MAC, which is then in charge to find the right destination address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can achieve that behaviour by introducing a simple state machine. Just add a new variable in your UDP application's class, for example:

   ```
   int state; // 0 - beginning, 1 - waiting for P1 response, ...
   ```

   After sending a packet to P1 set this variable:

   ```
   state = 1;
   ```

   Then in `handleMessageWhenUp()` add an additional condition, for example:

   ```
   void UDPBasicApp::handleMessageWhenUp(cMessage *msg) {
     if (!msg->isSelfMessage() && msg->getKind() == UDP_I_DATA) {
       if (state == 0) {
         // ...
       } else if (state == 1) {
         // take source address
         cPacket *pk = PK(msg);
         UDPDataIndication *ctrl = check_and_cast<UDPDataIndication *>(pk->removeControlInfo());
         L3Address srcAddress = ctrl->getSrcAddr();
         // check if srcAddress is equal to P1 address
         // if equals: 
         //   1) send a packet to P2 
         //   2) set state = 2
         // do nothing if srcAddress is not equal to P1

       } else if (state == 2) {
        // ...
       }
      }
   }
   ```
2. `globalARP` uses one static table, shared by all hosts in the network. During initialization each host inserts own addresses into this table. Therefore, after initialization the table contains all addresses. Host which has `arpType = GlobalARP` never sends an ARP request, instead of sending it just looks for entry in this table.
3. The network layer works transparently for UDP application. An instance of `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` assigns addresses to all interfaces that need them. So you do not need to do anything else for the network layer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply, I do have a problem though, I get this error
`check_and_cast(): cannot cast nullptr to type 'inet::UDPDataIndication *'.` upon the reception of the message from UDPEchoApp. Do you know why? Is it because of a specific packet structure?

Comment: Probably a self message has been processed as a UDP packet. Unfortunately, `UDP_I_DATA` is equal to 0, the same kind value uses self messages. I have updated my example and added a new condition, it should resolve that problem.

Comment: Still not working. What I have is actually something like this:
`if (msg->isSelfMessage()) { //..} else if (msg->getKind() == UDP_I_DATA){//...}` so it should already filter the self messages

Comment: It seems that a `cPacket` object which is not a UDP packet is received in your module. Could you show what exactly you send from module?